# For variable = SheetName1 to SheetName2

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub my_code_sht1()

  Sheets("Sht1").select
  '------------------
  '------MY CODE-----
  '------------------
End sub

Sub my_code_sht2()

  Sheets("Sht2").select
  '------------------
  '------MY CODE-----
  '------------------
End sub
```

"MY CODE" is exactly the same for my 2 sub.
Now I'd like to know if it's possible to regroup these two pieces of code like this:

```
Sub my_code()

  For string = "Sht1" to "Sht2"
    Sheets("string").select
    '------------------
    '------MY CODE-----
    '------------------
  Next string
End sub
```

Is something like that possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way, not that you need to select each sheet

```
Sub my_code()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets(Array("Sht1", "Sht2"))
    ws.Select
    'code
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just be careful using `Sheets` on it's own - if you have multiple workbooks open it's not difficult to get an error. Good practice would be to specify the workbook the sheets are in or if it's the same workbook the code is in, use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you code extract your code into its own subroutine and pass the sheet name as a parameter or you could use a `ParamArray` to pass in a variable number of sheet names.

```
Sub my_code_sht1()
    ProcessWorkSheet "Sht1"
    ProcessWorkSheet "Sht2"
    ProcessWorkSheetsArray "Sht1", "Sht2"
End Sub


Sub ProcessWorkSheet(SheetName As String)
    Sheets(SheetName).Select
    '------------------
    '------MY CODE-----
    '------------------
End Sub

Sub ProcessWorkSheetsArray(ParamArray SheetNames())
    Dim vName As Variant
    For Each vName In SheetNames
        Sheets(vName).Select
        '------------------
        '------MY CODE-----
        '------------------
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, thank you for this precision, it looks a bit like a java code (i'm totally new in java, that's why i'm saying that ^^). I used the code of @SJR but this method is interesting. Thank you for your time (and your edit). Have a good day Thomas! =)

Comment: SJR post is the exact answer to your question.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, you too (not the first time you help me by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with array and for loop. It does not use for each, but it checks the length of the array:

```
Sub my_code()

    dim arr_names   as variant
    dim l_counter   as long

    arr_names = Array("Sht1", "Sht2", "Sht3")

    for l_counter = lbound(arr_names) to ubound(arr_names)
        sheets(arr_names(l_counter)).select
        'code
    next l_counter

end sub
```

Comment: thank you, this is too specific for my usage, but i'm sure it will be usefull for someone! =)

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the same code, then first `

```
Sub DoWithSheet(wks As Worksheet)
    ' Code for the Worksheet
    Debug.Print wks.Name
    ' and more   
End Sub
```

And then for two  sheets only

```
DowithSheet Sheets("Sht1")
DoWithSheet Sheets("Sht2")
```